# Validating an XML against referenced XSD in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have an XML file with a specified schema location such as this:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="someurl ..\localSchemaPath.xsd"
```

I want to validate in C#.  Visual Studio, when I open the file, validates it against the schema and lists errors perfectly.  Somehow, though, I can't seem to validate it automatically in C# without specifying the schema to validate against like so:

```
XmlDocument asset = new XmlDocument();

XmlTextReader schemaReader = new XmlTextReader("relativeSchemaPath");
XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(schemaReader, SchemaValidationHandler);

asset.Schemas.Add(schema);

asset.Load(filename);
asset.Validate(DocumentValidationHandler);
```

Shouldn't I be able to validate with the schema specified in the XML file automatically ?  What am I missing ?

Comment: Refer the MSDN sample : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.validationeventargs.severity.aspx

Answer (score 179, accepted):

You need to create an XmlReaderSettings instance and pass that to your XmlReader when you create it. Then you can subscribe to the `ValidationEventHandler` in the settings to receive validation errors. Your code will end up looking like this:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.IO;

public class ValidXSD
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        // Set the validation settings.
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
        settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);

        // Create the XmlReader object.
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("inlineSchema.xml", settings);

        // Parse the file. 
        while (reader.Read()) ;

    }
    // Display any warnings or errors.
    private static void ValidationCallBack(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
            Console.WriteLine("\tWarning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred." + args.Message);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("\tValidation error: " + args.Message);

    }
}
```

Comment: +1 although should update to use `using` clause for completeness :)

Comment: If you're looking to compare against an XSD file add the following line to the above code: settings.Schemas.Add("YourDomainHere", "yourXSDFile.xsd");

Comment: To get Line# and position# of the error simply use: args.Exception.LineNumber... in ValidationCallBack

Comment: What if the schema i have doesn't have a namespace?

Comment: What's means ***inlineSchema*** for the _xml file_ ? And if I have **xml file** with `xmlns:xsi, xmlns and xsi:schemaLocation`, and I have **xsd file** with `targetNamespace, xmlns, and xmlns:xs` ? [full files](https://gist.github.com/kiquenet/86090779650975b7426a7f798174eef6)

Comment: Using ***lambda***, better IMHO, more _clarity code_ `settings.ValidationEventHandler += (o, args) =>
            {
                errors = true; 
                // More code
            };`

Comment: you are looking for ProcessInlineSchema. Defined in XML itself. Above solution is correct for it.

Comment: When compare  against an XSD file, you can use :
settings.Schemas.Add("xml file schema namespace", "path to xsd file");

If the there is no "xml file schema namespace", you can use :
settings.Schemas.Add(null, "path to xsd file");

Answer (score 123):

A simpler way, if you are using .NET 3.5, is to use `XDocument` and `XmlSchemaSet` validation.

```
XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add(schemaNamespace, schemaFileName);

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
string msg = "";
doc.Validate(schemas, (o, e) => {
    msg += e.Message + Environment.NewLine;
});
Console.WriteLine(msg == "" ? "Document is valid" : "Document invalid: " + msg);
```

See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340331.aspx) for more assistance.

Comment: That method requires you know the schema beforehand rather than taking the inline schema from the xml.

Comment: this works fine but throws error when xml document contains some html tag like <catalog>my <i> new </i> catalog....</catalog>


in above case html tags like "<i>" creates an issue as it is the value of "<catalog>" ... how to validate it

Comment: @AnilPurswani: If you wish to put HTML into an XML document, you need to wrap it in CDATA. `<catalog><![CDATA[my <i> new </i> catalog....]]></catalog>` is the correct way to do that.

Comment: Simple and elegant! This works very well when validating against a fixed schema set (which is our case, and a big one with multiple folders and files). I'm already thinking about caching the XmlSchemaSet to be reused between calls to the Validator. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It does not work when the default namespace in XSD is different than in XML.

Answer (score 24):

personally I favor validating without a callback:

```
public bool ValidateSchema(string xmlPath, string xsdPath)
{
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load(xmlPath);

    xml.Schemas.Add(null, xsdPath);

    try
    {
        xml.Validate(null);
    }
    catch (XmlSchemaValidationException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

(see Timiz0r's post in [Synchronous XML Schema Validation? .NET 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719022/synchronous-xml-schema-validation-net-3-5))

Comment: The callback provides you with some extra information about which line in your xml is not correct. This method is very binary, either right or wrong :)

Comment: you can get the exception message :)

Answer (score 22):

The following [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5d30c9(v=vs.110).aspx) validates an XML file and generates the appropriate error or warning.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;

public class Sample
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        //Load the XmlSchemaSet.
        XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schemaSet.Add("urn:bookstore-schema", "books.xsd");

        //Validate the file using the schema stored in the schema set.
        //Any elements belonging to the namespace "urn:cd-schema" generate
        //a warning because there is no schema matching that namespace.
        Validate("store.xml", schemaSet);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Validate(String filename, XmlSchemaSet schemaSet)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nValidating XML file {0}...", filename.ToString());

        XmlSchema compiledSchema = null;

        foreach (XmlSchema schema in schemaSet.Schemas())
        {
            compiledSchema = schema;
        }

        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.Schemas.Add(compiledSchema);
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

        //Create the schema validating reader.
        XmlReader vreader = XmlReader.Create(filename, settings);

        while (vreader.Read()) { }

        //Close the reader.
        vreader.Close();
    }

    //Display any warnings or errors.
    private static void ValidationCallBack(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
            Console.WriteLine("\tWarning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred." + args.Message);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("\tValidation error: " + args.Message);

    }
}
```

The preceding example uses the following input files.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<bookstore xmlns="urn:bookstore-schema" xmlns:cd="urn:cd-schema">
  <book genre="novel">
    <title>The Confidence Man</title>
    <price>11.99</price>
  </book>
  <cd:cd>
    <title>Americana</title>
    <cd:artist>Offspring</cd:artist>
    <price>16.95</price>
  </cd:cd>
</bookstore>
```

books.xsd

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="urn:bookstore-schema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="urn:bookstore-schema">

 <xsd:element name="bookstore" type="bookstoreType"/>

 <xsd:complexType name="bookstoreType">
  <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
   <xsd:element name="book"  type="bookType"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>

 <xsd:complexType name="bookType">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="author" type="authorName"/>
   <xsd:element name="price"  type="xsd:decimal"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="genre" type="xsd:string"/>
 </xsd:complexType>

 <xsd:complexType name="authorName">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="first-name"  type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="last-name" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 13):

I had do this kind of automatic validation in VB and this is how I did it (converted to C#):

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.ValidationFlags = settings.ValidationFlags |
                           Schema.XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
XmlReader XMLvalidator = XmlReader.Create(reader, settings);
```

Then I subscribed to the `settings.ValidationEventHandler` event while reading the file.