# Validating an XML file(Schematron file) against XSD using MSBuild

Tags: xml, validation, batch-file, powershell, msbuild

In my project, I am using several schematron(XML) files and build the project using MSBuild script.

Is there any way in **MSBuild** or in **Powershell** Commands to validate those XML files against XSD file like `<validatexml>` tag in NAnt??

If yes, then Please provide any example that shows how can we do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822907/how-do-i-use-powershell-to-validate-xml-files-against-an-xsd

Comment: Thanks @Naigel for Powershell Commands.Is there any way in MSBuild for that or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) there is a `Test-Xml` cmdlet that will validate XML e.g.

```
<Exec Command='PowerShell.exe -Command "& {Test-Xml -Path $(XmlPath) -Validate}"/>
```

Avoid using the `-File` parameter on PowerShell.exe.  Certain versions of PowerShell don't return the correct exit code when this parameter is used.