# Get PowerShell to honour the data type specified in xml schema (xsd)

Tags: xml, powershell, xsd

I'm using PowerShell to pass an XML file. Certain values need be of type integer.
I have built (or Visual Studio has) an XSD schema file to support my XML in an attempt to specify data types. In the XSD, I specify the data type, and VS intellisense suggests the XSD is correct as when I change an int to a string it complains. However, when it is passed through PowerShell, the data type  returned is a string.

Is there a way to get PowerShell to use the data type specified in the XSD?

#### XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd">
  <phase value="build">
    <component role="database">
      <title value="a new database" />
      <vmQty>1</vmQty>
    </component>
    <component role="application">
      <title value="an app" />
      <vmQty>1</vmQty>
    </component>
  </phase>
  <phase value="configure">
    <component role="database">
      <databaseName value ="new world DB" />
    </component>
    <component role="application">
      <appName value="new world app" />
    </component>
  </phase>
</test>
```

#### XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <element name="test">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="phase">
          <complexType>
            <sequence>
              <element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="component">
                <complexType>
                  <sequence>
                    <element minOccurs="0" name="appName">
                      <complexType>
                        <attribute name="value" type="string" use="required" />
                      </complexType>
                    </element>
                    <element minOccurs="0" name="databaseName">
                      <complexType>
                        <attribute name="value" type="string" use="required" />
                      </complexType>
                    </element>
                    <element minOccurs="0" name="title">
                      <complexType>
                        <attribute name="value" type="string" use="required" />
                      </complexType>
                    </element>
                    <element minOccurs="0" name="vmQty" type="integer" />
                  </sequence>
                  <attribute name="role" type="string" use="required" />
                </complexType>
              </element>
            </sequence>
            <attribute name="value" type="string" use="required" />
          </complexType>
        </element>
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>
</schema>
```

#### PowerShell

```
$path = "D:\Temp\XML\test.xml"
$xpath = $xPath = "//phase[@value='build']/component"

$oXml = [xml](Get-Content -Path $Path)
$xPathObject = $oXml | Select-Xml -xpath $xPath

$Return = [ordered]@{}
$xPathObject.Node | ForEach-Object{
    $Role = $_.Role
     $childNodes = $_.ChildNodes 

    $childNodes | ForEach-Object{

        if($_.InnerXml)
        {
            #e.g <number>1</vmQty>
            $Return.$Role += [ordered]@{$_.name = $_.InnerXml}
        }
        else
        {
           #e.g <number value="1" />
           $Return.$Role += [ordered]@{$_.name = $_.value}
        }
    }
}

$Return
```

Return object:

```
PS C:\> $Return.database
Name                           Value                                                                                     
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                              
title                          a new database                                                                                                                                                     
vmQty                          1
```

Check data type of vmQty:

```
PS C:\> $Return.database.vmQty.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                               
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                               
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

In the XML, I have added `xs:type="integer"` to `<vmQty>1</vmQty>`, however this results in Intellisense reporting `This is an invalid  xsi:type 'integer'.`

And just to check it's not my poor coding at work, as simple as I can get it;

```
$path = "D:\Temp\XML\test.xml"
$oXml = [xml](Get-Content -Path $Path)

$oxml.test.phase[0].component[0].vmQty.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                               
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                               
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

It still return a string.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822907/how-do-i-use-powershell-to-validate-xml-files-against-an-xsd).