# Example to validate xml against xsd in Go language?

Tags: xml, go, xsd

I have been trying to use different Go packages for validating xml against xsd and no luck in efficiently using them.

`github.com/goxmpp/xml`

`github.com/lestrrat-go/libxml2`

`github.com/go-xmlpath/xmlpath`

`github.com/metaleap/go-xsd/types`

I either get compilation failures or unable to install the required dependencies.

Can anyone please provide a package available in Go and also a working example to test any xml against specified schema definition file (xsd)?

Comment: You can use powershell to validate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822907/how-do-i-use-powershell-to-validate-xml-files-against-an-xsd

Comment: Thanks @jdweng but I need a program in Go language to run atleast on laptop.

Comment: Powershell is install on windows.  Should run on your laptop.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few packages that you can use to validate XML against XSD in Go:

[xsdvalidate](https://github.com/terminalstatic/go-xsd-validate) is a package that uses libxml2 to validate XML. It is a good choice if you need to validate XML quickly and efficiently.

[go-xsd](https://github.com/metaleap/go-xsd) is another package that uses libxml2 to validate XML. It is a bit more complex to use than `xsdvalidate`, but it offers more features.

[xmlpath](https://github.com/go-xmlpath/xmlpath) is a package that can be used to parse and validate XML. It is a good choice if you need to do more complex validations, such as checking for the presence of specific elements or attributes.

Here is a code example using `xsdvalidate`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/terminalstatic/go-xsd-validate"
)

func main() {
    // Load the XSD file.
    xsdHandler, err := xsdvalidate.NewXsdHandlerFromFile("my_schema.xsd")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Load the XML document.
    xmlData, err := ioutil.ReadFile("my_xml.xml")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Validate the XML document against the XSD.
    err = xsdHandler.Validate(xmlData)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("XML document is valid")
    }
}
```

If you want an example for other packages please lemme know, then I can put something.

Comment: Thanks! I get compile error, NewXsdHandlerFromFile not declared by package xsdvalidate and also runtime error, # pkg-config --cflags  -- libxml-2.0
pkg-config: exec: "pkg-config": executable file not found in %PATH%

Comment: now issue solved?

Comment: same error coming

Comment: please confirm your gopath