# In .NET, does the entire XML blob come into memory when I validate against a XSD?

Tags: .net, validation, xsd, xmlreader

If I have a large (>500MB) XML file to validate, does an XmlReader bring the whole thing into memory to perform validation?

I looked at [Validating an XML against referenced XSD in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751511/validating-an-xml-against-referenced-xsd-in-c) for validation procedure.

thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you use `XmlValidatingReader` (or `XmlReader` with appropriate settings) it won't load the whole XML file. The method described in the **question** uses `XmlDocument` class which **does** load the whole file. The **accepted answer** doesn't load the entire file so you'll be fine using it.

Comment: Can you please explain which XmlReader settings should be used to ensure that we don't have the entire 500+ MB xml in memory during validation?

Comment: No specific settings. I meant appropriate settings to turn on validation. XmlReader doesn't load the whole document in general. However, you should enable validation if you want (as described in the answer).