# secure upload with uploadify and asp.net mvc 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, uploadify

i have an asp.net mvc 2 application and i am using uploadify. I am uploading the files straight into a sql server db. What are the necessary checks i need to do and how? I would like to perform a anti virus scan? what are possible security loopholes here?

Comment: Are you parsing the XML on the server or you are storing the uploaded stream directly as a BLOB into the database?

Comment: the xml is stored as a blob in the db

Answer (score 0):

You could try feeding the uploaded stream into a [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) and parse through it. In the event of an exception chances are that there is something wrong with this *XML file*:

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(uploadedFile.InputStream))
{
    try
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        { }
        // At this stage you may save the XML file into the database. 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // probably not a valid XML file
    }
}
```

If the uploaded XML files need to obey a certain structure you could validate them against an XSD schema by [specifying this to the XmlReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751511/validating-an-xml-against-referenced-xsd-in-c/752774#752774).