# How to do command line XPath queries in huge XML files?

Tags: xml, xpath, xmllint

I have a collection of XML files, and some of them are pretty big (up to ~50 million element nodes). I am using `xmllint` for validating those files, which works pretty nicely even for the huge ones thanks to the streaming API.

```
xmllint --loaddtd --stream --valid /path/to/huge.xml
```

I recently learned that `xmllint` is also capable of doing command line XPath queries, which is very handy.

```
xmllint --loaddtd --xpath '/root/a/b/c/text()' /path/to/small.xml
```

However, these XPath queries do not work for the huge XML files. I just receive a "Killed" message after some time. I tried to enable the streaming API, but this just leads to no output at all.

```
xmllint --loaddtd --stream --xpath '/root/a/b/c/text()' /path/to/huge.xml
```

Is there a way to enable streaming mode when doing XPath queries using `xmllint`? Are there other/better ways to do command line XPath queries for huge XML files?

Comment: try `--shell` option for interactive (with just the xml file path)

Comment: I tried opening the interactive shell for a huge file, but it will crash ("Killed", just as in the case of not using `--stream`) before I can enter any command.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/543881/efficiently-extracting-a-few-data-from-a-large-xml-file

Comment: attaching a sample XML file would help – I, for one, have no idea what **large** might mean in your case.

Comment: Think of something like the dblp XML dump (http://dblp.dagstuhl.de/xml/). I receive the "Killed" error when parsing that file in a non-streaming context. But my question is aimed at essentially any file that is big enough such that you would be ill advised to build a DOM in main memory and should rather use a streaming approach instead.

Comment: What about using [XSLT 3.0 streaming functions](http://www.stylusstudio.com/tutorials/intro-xslt-3.html) for that? It could be more predictable and safer.

Comment: Internally, `libxml2` has some support for streaming XPath expressions, but `xmllint` (the command-line interface to `libxml2`) doesn't support the combination of `--xpath` and `--stream`.

Answer (score 5):

If your XPath expressions are very simple, try [xmlcutty](https://github.com/miku/xmlcutty).

From the homepage:

> xmlcutty is a simple tool for carving out elements from large XML files, fast. Since it works in a streaming fashion, it uses almost no memory and can process around 1G of XML per minute.

Comment: A command like `xmllint --loaddtd --xpath '/root/a/b/c/text()' /path/to/small.xml` would be translated into `xmlcutty -path '/root/a/b/c' -rename '\n' /path/to/small.xml` - where the *rename* is meant to rename the last enclosing element - and thus simulating a `text()` - the syntax is bit arcane.

Answer (score -1):

change `ulimits` might work. Try this:

```
$ ulimit -Sv 500000
$ xmllint (...your command)
```