# Schema validation on 5GB xml file

Tags: python, xml, xsd, lxml, elementtree

I am using the following to verify a large 5GB XML document:

```
from lxml.etree fromstring, XMLSchema

xmlschema = XMLSchema(xmlschema_doc)
root = fromstring(open(myfilepath).read())
xmlschema.assertValid(root)
```

However, I'm starting to hit out of memory errors:

> OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory

Is there a 'on-the-fly' way to do xsd validation in xml without having to load everything into memory? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: Does it need to be in python? Otherwise see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528249/how-to-validate-very-large-xml-files

Comment: You're looking for a python sax library

Comment: I don't know what's available in the Python world, but in the Java world Xerces and Saxon can both do on-the-fly validation. (However, with 5GB, even the space occupied by the indexes needed to do ID/key/unique/keyref validation can consume quite a bit of memory, depending of course on the schema).