# Deploy web service from xsd to receive messages

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, xsd, computer-science

I have to publish a web service (with .net) to receive messages from another web service. I only have the .xsd of the messages and an example of one request.

I've been able to create the .cs files from the .xsd but now I do not know how to deploy the web service from that .cs files.

Can anyone help me with an example or some code?

Comment: You need to create a ontract for your service add your method you wanna call and your implementation , host your service and that s it

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627503/how-to-create-a-web-service-that-receives-and-sends-xml-based-on-xsd-files