# Check XML via XSD schemas which are specified in xsi:schemaLocation attribute

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xsd

Sorry for my English.

C# 4.0, LINQ to XML.

I get XDocument from an XML file, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../../support/localization.xslt"?>
<doc:resources xmlns:doc="http://mea-orbis.com/2012/XMLSchema/localization"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://mea-orbis.com/2012/XMLSchema/localization ../../support/localization.xsd">
  <!--Заголовки столбцов таблицы-->
  <doc:record id="commandName">Команда</doc:record>
  <doc:record id="commandNameDescript">Краткое описание</doc:record>
  <doc:record id="commandNameNotes">Примечание</doc:record>
  <!--******************************************-->

  <!--Наименования групп команд-->
  <doc:record id="group1">Команды смены кодировок</doc:record>

  <!--******************************************-->

  <!--Наименования команд, их краткое описание и примечания-->
  <doc:record id="dwgconvertName">DWGCONVERT</doc:record>
  <doc:record id="dwgconvertKeyWords">кодировка</doc:record>
  <doc:record id="dwgconvertDescr">конвертация текущего чертежа (версии AutoCAD до 2011 включительно)</doc:record>

  <doc:record id="dwgconvertcpName">DWGCONVERTCP</doc:record>
  <doc:record id="dwgconvertcpKeyWords">кодировка</doc:record>
  <doc:record id="dwgconvertcpDescr">конвертация текущего чертежа (версии AutoCAD с 2008)</doc:record>

  <doc:record id="dwgconvertfilesName">DWGCONVERTFILES</doc:record>
  <doc:record id="dwgconvertfilesKeyW">кодировка</doc:record>
  <doc:record id="dwgconvertfilesDescr">конвертация выбранных пользователем чертежей</doc:record>

  <doc:record id="dwgconvertstrName">DWGCONVERTSTR</doc:record>
  <doc:record id="dwgconvertstrKeyW">кодировка</doc:record>
  <doc:record id="dwgconvertstrDescr">
    конвертация отдельного текстового примитива (примитивов)
    из текущего чертежа
  </doc:record>
  <doc:record id="ns">DWGCONVERT</doc:record>

  <doc:record id="arxload">Загрузка всех ARX файлов</doc:record>
  <doc:record id="netload">Загрузка всех DLL файлов</doc:record>
</doc:resources>
```

I need to check XDocument for XSD schema validation.  I found two examples in MSDN:
[first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb340331.aspx), [second](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387037%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

But in the samples, the XSD schema is separate from the file.  I don't want to do superfluous operations because these schemas are already specified in the xsi:schemaLocation attribute of my XML file.

What is the correct way to execute a check of object XDocument, in which all necessary schemas are already specified in the xsi:schemaLocation attribute?

Regards

Comment: Can I clarify: is the point here "I already have those files locally, and don't want it going to http://mea-orbis.com to fetch them" ?

Comment: also: is it on option to do the validation via XmlReader instead? since this allows you to use an XmlResolver, and more specifically - the `XmlPreloadedResolver`, which *sounds* like what you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processing of xsi attributes for schema locations is not built in the framework; you will have to do that yourself.

The way I've done it involves the following steps:

- reading schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation attributes associated with your document root element. This is where you have to come up with your solution that best fits your needs; if you don't care about performance, then you can simply use the DOM based API - it may result in going over the source XML twice: once to parse it into memory, then again to validate it. Or, you use a fast, forward only reader to only read all the attributes of the root node, looking for your xsi: ones, then abandon the reading once past the root element.
- Once found, you'll have to parse the attribute values; typically you invoke a string.Split() on whitespace (\t, \r, \n, 0x20), trimming all, discarding empties and making pairs (when namespaces are used). Ultimately, this gives you the list of URIs where your XSDs are located
- For each URI, resolve it to an absolute URI, eventually converting any relative using the base absolute URI of your XML file
- Build an [XmlSchemaSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset.aspx) by adding all the XSDs; compile it and use it for validation by getting a reader from your source XML.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little late, but I found this question, and then I found this answer elsewhere on Stack Overflow:
 [Validating an XML against referenced XSD in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751511/validating-an-xml-against-referenced-xsd-in-c-sharp). 
I just checked that it worked at least for a locally stored xsd.