# Why is my XmlReader not validating against the Schema?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to read an XML file and validate against the schema specified by that file. I will not know the schema's location ahead of time, so I need to use the schema specified by the xml file.

Here's the relevant code (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/752774/1991068)):

```cs
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationFailed);
//settings.Schemas.Add("http://www.publishing.org", new XmlTextReader(@"C:\path\to\schema\Book.xsd"));

validatingReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlInputReader, settings);
while (validatingReader.Read()) ;
```

If I uncomment the `settings.Schemas.Add` line and comment the `settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation` out, everything works. I have also tested both the schema and the XML against an external validator.

The event handler message reports "Cannot load the schema for the namespace 'http://www.publishing.org' - Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: baseUri." and it occurs on line 2 (at the root element), followed by "Could not find schema information for the element 'http://www.publishing.org:[each element]'.

My first thought (and still the only thing I know it can be) was that the URI wasn't pointing to the xsd, but I've used 1) A full path via file:///C:\path\to\schema\Book.xsd, 2) A URI relative to the xml file, and 3) A URI relative to the application's current directory. The Visual Studio XML editor has no problem with any of these, but the XmlReader can't seem to find any of them.

Here's a simple schema and an xml instance (my actual schema is more complex, but this fails too):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.publishing.org" xmlns="http://www.publishing.org"
    version="1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:element name="Book" type="BookType"/>

    <xsd:complexType name="BookType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="Author" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="Date" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="ISBN" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="Publisher" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Book xmlns="http://www.publishing.org" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.publishing.org ../etc/Book.xsd">
    <!-- Book.xsd file:///C:\path\to\schema\Book.xsd -->
    <Title>Historic Doubts Relative to Napoleon Bonaparte</Title>
    <Author>Richard Whately</Author>
    <Author>Whately, Richard</Author>
    <Date>1849</Date>
    <ISBN>1465554777</ISBN>
    <Publisher>Warren P. Draper</Publisher>
</Book>
```

I think everything is correct concerning my namespaces. I have also tried loading through an XmlDocument, but I get the same results. It has to be a problem locating the XSD, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree it should be a path problem.
I was able to use your code ( and the example you used :) ) .

I tested the validation against a local copy of the xsd, in a file, by setting my local file path inside the xml.

It did nothing when I used your exact xml, and indeed threw the validation error if I changed a tag.

My xsi:schemaLocation looks like:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.publishing.org C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\xml_test_files\test.xsd"
```

Did you try that simple local folder path?