# upgrade/convert rdlc report files from VS2008 to VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, rdlc, report-viewer2010, reportviewer2008

I have a report (rdlc) file made on VS2008 and can work on both Report Viewer 2008 & 2010.

Then I converted the rdlc report file to Report Viewer 2010 by using `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition"` and using `<ReportSections>` appropriately inside the file. (I did this because when I open the report file in vs2010 it didn't gave any alert for converting the file; so I thought I could do it manually.)

After that manual conversion, I continued using VS2010 with Report Viewer 2010 in my project but it gives me an error text : "The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded."

I'm sure that the **Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms** assembly is version 10 in my project references. And also I used the following configurations in config file

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControl10" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      <!--<add name="ReportViewerWebControl9" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" resourceType="Unspecified" />-->
      ...
    </handlers>
    ...
</system.webServer>
...
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false" />
    <!--<add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false" />-->
    ...
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

So what is the problem? How can I convert rdlc files from 2008 to 2010 for the best? And if the problem is not caused by the rdlc itself how can I fix this? Is there a way to show the conversion popup in vs2010 as described [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20212689-20da-4315-8fb3-7190b4b93628/converting-an-rdlc-report-from-vs-2008-to-vs-2010?forum=vsreportcontrols)?

Comment: I've had issues converting in the past too. What I ended up doing was creating a new blank report. Setting up the parameters/datasets manually then copying and pasting the content from the old template to the new template.

Comment: @David , well, I tried that too: I opened up Visual Studio 2010 and created a web project and I added a Report File (rdlc) to the project. Then I made some customizations. Finally I wondered what xmlns it is being used inside rdlc file: İt was

`xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition"`

so, is the report viewer version 2010 a myth?

Comment: By the way, I used [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751511/validating-an-xml-against-referenced-xsd-in-c-sharp) to check if there is any validation error in Report File (rdlc). There is no error :)