# c# validate xml against multiple xsd and get the associated/matching xsd

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd, schema

I have a `TCP` network protocoll where the informations/data are sent as `xml documents`. Now I would like to match these informations against multiple `xsd` files. The data is beeing received randomly, so I would like to know which information is coming by validating them against my `xsd files`.

*I have already created the xsd files (~25) which should match*

In the second step, I would like to create an instance of a `customClass` based on the matched `xsd` file.

The first part of my question has already been answered on SO. For my second question, I need some help.

#### 1 How to validate a xml against multiple xsd

- already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11801566/6229375

```
private void _LoadSchemaSet()
{
    _Logger.Debug("Loading schemata..");
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var specs = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Where(r => r.ToLower().StartsWith("myCompany.myCustomer.specs") && r.EndsWith(".xsd"));
    foreach (string spec in specs)
    {
        _Logger.Trace(spec);
        _SchemaSet.Add(XmlSchema.Read(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(spec), _Schema_ValidationEventHandler));
    }
}


public bool ValidateXDocument(XDocument document)
{
    bool result = true;
    document.Validate(_SchemaSet, (sender, args) => { result = false; });

    // at this point I would like to get the xsd file which matches

    return result;
}
```

#### 2 How to get the xsd file which matches the xml file

Comment: Either the XML file has a schema specified in the file or you have to manually build he schema from scratch.

Comment: I have updated my question, with some more infos. The XML does not have any schema informations. I have already build my ~25 schemata and would like to match the unknown xml against them. In second step I parse it into a `customClass` based on the xsd file

Comment: What I usually suggest is loading the c# classes with test data and then serialize to produce an xml file.  Then compare the unknown xml against the serialized xml.