# Schema file caching during node selection from XML with namespaces using XPathDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xpath

I am selecting nodes using `XPathDocument` from XML containing namespaces.
Appropriate namespace has been added:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nav.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("nsABC", @"http://www.thesite.com/xsd/XYZ123.xsd");
```

Once selecting a node using `Select("XPathExpression")`:

1. Will `xsd` file be download from the external server each time the Select method is executed?
2. Will `xsd` file be downloaded once and cached during app life-time, or in the system?

Providing wrong URI in `nsmgr.AddNamespace`, casues `Select` to NOT recognise nodes, so this is a proof that it has to be aware of `xsd` file, thus it had to be downloaded.

3. What about running app for the first time on other PC without internet access, where there is no chance to have this `xsd` cached anywhere. Where 'xsd' was is taken from? I have tested this option and code was executed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer all of your three questions at once: No. The `.xsd` file will not be downloaded - neither on the first run nor on the following runs. By adding the namespace URI with

```
nsmgr.AddNamespace("nsABC", @"http://www.thesite.com/xsd/XYZ123.xsd");
```

you merely create a link between the namespace prefix and the namespace URI. The latter is [defined as](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/#ns-decl)

> The attribute's value, a URI reference, is the namespace name identifying the namespace. The namespace name, to serve its intended purpose, should have the characteristics of uniqueness and persistence. **It is not a goal that it be directly usable for retrieval of a schema (if any exists).** An example of a syntax that is designed with these goals in mind is that for Uniform Resource Names [RFC2141]. However, it should be noted that ordinary URLs can be managed in such a way as to achieve these same goals.

Downloading and validating an XML against an XSD schema has to be done separately. An example using `XmlDocument` is ["Validating an XML against referenced XSD in C#"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/751511/1305969).

Comment: Clear, so why it does not work (recognise nodes) once URI points to wrong / not existing `xsd` file?

Comment: If don't know the XML, but if the _string_ differs from the one used/defined in the XML, it won't work.