# How can I convert a file URL to a file path to pass into an executable as an argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I am building a web app which works with XML files. One of the things the app needs to do is validate the XML files against specific schemas. For that, I am using an open source tool which runs using an .exe command, into which I pass in the schema file path and the XML file path, and it outputs messages.

I can get the validation tool running perfectly well if i just pass it a local file path for the XML file, but the XML files are held in an Azure DB. The best I can do is a https:// URL to the XML file.

With this in mind, and without going down the route of WebDavs or copying the file from the server, is there a simple way to get the data from the URL path and convert it into a file path that will be accepted by the .exe tool?

Comment: Maybe cURL? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL

Comment: Using an external tool for that seems a little messy/hacky in my eyes. Have you looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/752774/3034273) (also note the comment if you have XSD files to validate against). Then you just need to open an XmlReader with the XML data

Comment: @Xerillio thanks for that, and if it were just the validation i were using the tool for i'd agree, but there are other functions too. I was just trying to keep it simple using that as an example.

Comment: @Daedalus is it a custom EXE or is it some official tool? Have you checked that it actually supports reading files/data over the network? If not, I would say you're out of luck regarding a simple solution