# c# comparing XML format

Tags: c#, xml, format

I am trying to compare XML user input to a valid XML string. What I do is remove the values from the user input and compare it to the valid XML. At the bottom you can see my code. But as you can see in the XML examples the user input the `goodslines` has two `goodsline` children and fewer children. How can i alter my code so that it can this case would return true when compared? Thanks in advance

**Valid XML**

```
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
                <goodslines>
                    <goodsline>
                        <unitamount></unitamount>
                        <unit_id matchmode="1"></unit_id>
                        <product_id matchmode="1"></product_id>
                        <weight></weight>
                        <loadingmeter></loadingmeter>
                        <volume></volume>
                        <length></length>
                        <width></width>
                        <height></height>
                    </goodsline>
                </goodslines>
```

**User input**

```
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
                <goodslines>
                    <goodsline>
                        <unitamount>5</unitamount>
                        <unit_id matchmode="1">colli</unit_id>
                        <product_id matchmode="1">1109</product_id>
                        <weight>50</weight>
                        <loadingmeter>0.2</loadingmeter>
                        <volume>0.036</volume>
                        <length>20</length>
                        <width>20</width>
                        <height>90</height>
                    </goodsline>
                    <goodsline>
                        <unitamount>12</unitamount>
                        <unit_id matchmode="1">drums</unit_id>
                        <product_id matchmode="1">1109</product_id>
                        <weight>345</weight>
                    </goodsline>
                </goodslines>
```

**Code**

```
        public static string Format(string xml)
        {
            try
            {
                var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                var element = XDocument.Parse(xml);

                var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
                {
                    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
                    Indent = true,
                    IndentChars = new string(' ', 3),
                    NewLineChars = Environment.NewLine,
                    NewLineOnAttributes = false,
                    NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace
                };

                using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder, settings))
                    element.Save(xmlWriter);

                return stringBuilder.ToString();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return "Unable to format XML" + ex;
            }
        }

        public static bool Compare(string xmlA, string xmlB)
        {
            if(xmlA == null || xmlB == null)
                return false;

            var xmlFormattedA = Format(xmlA);
            var xmlFormattedB = Format(xmlB);

            return xmlFormattedA.Equals(xmlFormattedB, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }

        public static string NoText(string request)
        {
            string pattern = @"<.*?>";
            Regex rg = new Regex(pattern);
            var noTextArr = rg.Matches(request)
                    .Cast<Match>()
                    .Select(m => m.Value)
                    .ToArray();
            string noText = string.Join("", noTextArr);
            return noText;
        }
```

Comment: You should validate against a schema instead of a dummy XML string. See [How to validate using XSD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/validate-xsd)

Comment: You'd also have to account for the order of elements. Validating against the schema would take care of that for you. Also you don't appear to be using your `NoText` method (at least in what you've posted here).

Comment: @CodeStranger In the example the xmlFormattedB is the result of NoText(). But it happens in the main. :)

Comment: Close as a duplicate of [Validating an XML against referenced XSD in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/751511/3744182) this?  [This answer specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11798194/3744182) shows how to do a streaming validation without having to load the entire XML into memory.